# Unable to fetch 0x contract from Etherscan and brownie

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to test a smart contract which import 0x in brownie ecosystem. I have the following error when importing from explorer or from abi, also it looks like solc doesn't take in count the dependency I've install on my computer

```
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

    /home/merklejerk/code/0x-protocol/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/external/IFlashWallet.sol:23:1: ParserError: Source "@0x/contracts-utils/contracts/src/v06/interfaces/IOwnableV06.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
    import "@0x/contracts-utils/contracts/src/v06/interfaces/IOwnableV06.sol";

^------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the compiler does not solve the relative path in the correct way.

Maybe the path of the file you import is wrong or not built properly from the compiler: when importing the file `IOwnableV06.sol` try to remove the `@` symbol and replace it with `./` or `../` depending on your project folder structure. For example `import "../../0x/the-path-here/File.sol";`

Or the file you want to import might not be in the allowed paths:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/using-the-compiler.html#how-it-works
(search for `--allow-paths`).

Comment: In fact , I'm using brownie and calling this the ```IOwnableV06.sol``` from etherscan, the file isn't on my local repository. the problen came from how brownie handle the fetching and compile from hosted contracts

Comment: Maybe you might import `IOwnableV06.sol` locally and remap the directory path: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compile.html?highlight=allowed%20path#path-remappings